# SFSpeechRecognizer multiple languages

Tags: ios, swift, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, sfspeechrecognizer

I am building a search that supports voice recognition and transforms speech to text so I am using `SFSpeechRecognizer`. But the problem is that I need to support multiple languages at the same time such as ("`en_US`", "`fr`", `vi`, `ar`).

The main idea is that the user can speak for example 1 word in English and the other in French and I want the engine to detect this.

Currently, I am using this to set my main language

ENGLISH:

```
private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "en_US"))!
```

FRENCH:

```
 private let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.init(identifier: "fr"))!
```

Every language I need to set it separately.

Is there a way so `SFSpeechRecognizer` supports multiple languages at the same time?

Comment: I'm also trying to achieve same but still no luck for me. Do you have any solutions? please let me know.

Comment: you need to make you own core ml model for Speech to text to detect multiple language support.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but no answer yet...

You cannot use more locale in just one `SFSpeechRecognizeer`, but you can manage multiple `SFSpeechRecognizer`s at the same time, like this:

```
let italian = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "it-IT"))
let english = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale(identifier: "en-US"))
```

set delegate for all of them:

```
italian.delegate = self
english.delegate = self
```

create double, triple or multiple logic as needed like:

```
self.recognitionTaskOne = italian?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
     // Your code
})
self.recognitionTaskTwo = english?.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
     // Your code
})
```

and so on...

For your specific request:

> The main idea is that the user can speak for example 1 word in English
> and the other in French and I want the engine to detect this.

I'm affraid that you need to process all the outputs and compare them. Anyway, I noticed that if I set one locale (for example Italian) and then the user speaks in English, the system gets some English too. This works just for English... I'm not sure, but I suppose that whatever locale you set, English is always understood by default.

Comment: HI @Giuseppe Garassino I have tried but for one of my request i am getting 
 SpeechApp[4764:92774] [Utility] +[AFAggregator logDictationFailedWithError:] Error Domain=kAFAssistantErrorDomain Code=203 "Retry" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Retry, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001c71470 {Error Domain=SiriSpeechErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"}}